# Upload file to server with wget command line

Tags: upload, wget, vtiger

I have web-page with button "Choose file" to upload file on server.

I am trying to upload file with wget command line to server. Exactly like we do it with "Choose file" button in web. 
I do this:

```
wget --load-cookies=cookies.txt --post-file '/root/vTiger/Organization.csv' http://vtiger.mydomain.com/link.php
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post request with Wget?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699666/post-request-with-wget)

Answer (score 3):

If that 'upload' operation is a submit to a multipart formpost HTML form, then the harsh truth is that wget doesn't support it. curl does though with its [-F](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-F) option.